# Apply feature class to feature class simulteaniously on multiple layers in Modelbuilder

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, feature-class

I am trying to create a model in modelbuilder that takes in multiple layers (the amount determined by the person using the tool in the end) and as a first step these layers should by copied with the tool **'feature class to feature class'** because the original layers are not allowed to be edited (they are from the company). However, feature class to feature class takes in only 1 input features.

Does anyone know how to perform this action on multiple layers at the same time?

Comment: [A quick tour of using iterators](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-iterators-for-iteration-looping-.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@NVaissier, since you are using ArcGISPRO you should take a look at this.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/iterators-for-looping.htm

In this article you will find more information about looping or batch or how ESRI calls them Iterators.